# Making the ID command to the class in a "legal" to allow WS3

Tags: css, class, html

On the [next page there are two rectangles](http://www.class-a-studio.co.il/mix_mastering06.php) in which written text.
(For illustrative purposes I put the CSS command before each rectangle ...)

The first rectangle -  ID  - command
The second rectangle  - span class  - command

I have two problems:

1 - design by span class command does not match (missing gap in the letters -  padding: 5px)

2 - something in the code of the span class is invalid for WC3 (problem with LI).

Comment: I don't see the problem. How should it look like?

Comment: If you've noticed - the top rectangle has a margin of letters in the frame.
So it is supposed to show the other with a command from a class

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for your second box is really messed up.  The first one is an `ol` element, but the second one is just a `span`.  You can't put the `li` inside something that is not a list(`ul` or `ol`).  You also close the span before you close the nested list item and the `p` element is closed last, even though it is a child of the `li`.

```
<span class ="commandmentsID1"> 
<li><p> 
    <!-- content here -->
</span></li></p>
```

should be:

```
<ol class ="commandmentsID1">   
<li><p> 
    <!-- same content here -->
</p></li></ol>
```

---

Since your CSS is exactly the same for both rectangles, you are better off just giving each a `class="commandment"` which has all of those CSS rules.

```
.commandment {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.commandment li {background:#292929; color:#d0d0d1; font:bold 5px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing:0px; margin:10px; padding:10px; text-align:center;}
.commandment li blockquote {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.commandment p {background:#333333; color:#ffffff; text-align:right; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing:0px; margin:0px; padding:5px; text-decoration:none;}

<ol class="commandment">
    <!-- content -->
</ol>
```

Comment: I'd love to know how I make the order of CLASS be true ...
To the design to be the same as the order by ID (upper rectangle)
And also - how to write the code correctly?
I'd be happy if you demonstrate it, please ....

Comment: As you can see - yet the letters do not move in ... like the example above ... padding:5px;
Something is not working right ...